# Is a non-zero homomorphism f: V ---> W of L-representations V,W surjective if W is simple?

Tags: lie-algebras

This could be wrong but: If W is simple then V must be simple and if V is simple then its only subrepresentations are 0 and V which means the Ker(F)=0 and thus F must be injective. But how can I show it it is surjective?

Comment: Why must $V$ be simple? What about a projection $V:=W\oplus W \twoheadrightarrow W$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$im(f) \subseteq W$ is a subrepresentation. So if $W$ is simple ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $W=sl(2,\mathbb{R})$, take a non zero element $x$ of $W$, $Vect(x)$ is a commutative algebra, and the canonical imbedding is not surjective.

Comment: But that embedding is not a homomorphism of representations.

Answer (score 0):

If $V, W$ are both simple L-modules Schur's lemma states that $f$ is either invertible or zero. However, since $f$ is by assumption non-zero, it must be invertible. Therefore, it is also surjective. However, this does not follow from your argumentation. See Torsten's reply for a (much) simpler argument.

Comment: So is it true then that if W is simple in this case then V must be also?

Comment: No, I don't see why that should be the case, see also Torsten's comment above. I've edited my answer to reflect this.